# Modify automatic table numbering in Latex

Tags: tables, numbering

I am writing a paper that includes a series of tables in the Annex.

all of the tables in my document are numbered, but I would like the tables in the annex to start a new numbering. Take the following table:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{My very interesting table is in the first in one in the Annex \label{tab:mytab}}
\small\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\centering}X>{\centering}X>{\centering}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{FIRST DV}     &\multicolumn{2}{c}{SECOND DV} \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         \\
\midrule

WTO Membership      &       0.045\sym{*}  &       0.051\sym{*}  &      -0.095         &      -0.190         \\
                    &     (0.023)         &     (0.026)         &     (0.078)         &     (0.116)         \\
Export \% of GDP    &       0.001         &       0.000         &       0.001         &       0.005         \\
                    &     (0.001)         &     (0.001)         &     (0.003)         &     (0.004)         \\
\midrule
N                   &     874.000         &     874.000         &     896.000         &     896.000         \\
Country FE          &         yes         &         yes         &         yes         &         yes         \\

Hansen J            &       0.971         &       0.960         &       0.193         &       0.937         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{p{\linewidth}}{\footnotesize my footnote}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

In the main text it produces the following output:

[image]

the table is correct, but it is numbered "Table 2" because it is the second table of the document.
Is there a way to change the numbering of the tables? My goal is twofold: first to add an "A" in front of the table numbering if these are in the Annex: something like, "Table A1" and "Table A2" the second is to restart counting with the Annex. Hence the first table in the annex should be numbered "Table A1" even if in the main text there are other tables that appear beforehand.

Here is the main tex file. perhaps is a problem with some of the headings?

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames*,x11names*}{xcolor}
%
\documentclass[
]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={title},
  pdfauthor={name},
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=Maroon,
  citecolor=Blue,
  urlcolor=Blue,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
% Set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fontsize=11pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\title{title}
\author{name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

{
\hypersetup{linkcolor=}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
}
\captionsetup{
  justification = centering
}

\begin{table}[!htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{This is a table in the main text \label{tab:mytab}}
\small\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\centering}X>{\centering}X>{\centering}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{FIRST DV}     &\multicolumn{2}{c}{SECOND DV} \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         \\
\midrule

IV      &       0.045\sym{*}  &       0.051\sym{*}  &      -0.095         &      -0.190         \\
                    &     (0.023)         &     (0.026)         &     (0.078)         &     (0.116)         \\
IV2    &       0.001         &       0.000         &       0.001         &       0.005         \\
                    &     (0.001)         &     (0.001)         &     (0.003)         &     (0.004)         \\
\midrule
N                   &     874.000         &     874.000         &     896.000         &     896.000         \\
Country FE          &         yes         &         yes         &         yes         &         yes         \\

Hansen J            &       0.971         &       0.960         &       0.193         &       0.937         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{p{\linewidth}}{\footnotesize my footnote}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\newpage
ANNEX

\begin{table}[!htbp]\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{My very interesting table is in the first in one in the Annex \label{tab:mytab}}
\small\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\centering}X>{\centering}X>{\centering}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{FIRST DV}     &\multicolumn{2}{c}{SECOND DV} \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         \\
\midrule

WTO Membership      &       0.045\sym{*}  &       0.051\sym{*}  &      -0.095         &      -0.190         \\
                    &     (0.023)         &     (0.026)         &     (0.078)         &     (0.116)         \\
Export \% of GDP    &       0.001         &       0.000         &       0.001         &       0.005         \\
                    &     (0.001)         &     (0.001)         &     (0.003)         &     (0.004)         \\
\midrule
N                   &     874.000         &     874.000         &     896.000         &     896.000         \\
Country FE          &         yes         &         yes         &         yes         &         yes         \\

Hansen J            &       0.971         &       0.960         &       0.193         &       0.937         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{p{\linewidth}}{\footnotesize my footnote}\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}





\end{document}
```

Comment: at the start of the appendix `\setcounter{table}{0} \renewcommand\thetable{A\arabic{table}}`

Comment: unrelated but you can replace `\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex`  by  `\usepackage{iftex}  \iftutex  luatex or xetex \else pdftex \fi`  (`ifxetex` and `ifluatex` packages are both just legacy packages that include `iftex` package these days)